# Why does my evaluation not display correctly in C?

Tags: c, printf

I'm doing my first assignment for my Programming in C class and thought the code was perfect, but the answer doesn't display correctly.

Help! What did I do wrong?

I've tried adjusting the syntax in variety of ways but still get nonsense output.

***Code***

```
int main(void){
    int num1;
    int num2;
    printf("Enter a whole number.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter a different whole number for evaluation.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num2);
    if(num1 > num2){
        printf ("%d is the larger number.\n", &num1);
    }
    else{
        printf ("%d is the larger number.\n", &num2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It should display the larger of the two numbers but instead the screen either disappears after entering the second number or else a longer string of numbers is displayed.

Comment: `printf ("%d is the larger number.\n", &num1);` should be `printf ("%d is the larger number.\n", num1);.` Also for `num2`

Comment: You are display the address of the variables rather than their values. Take out the & prefix in the last printf call.

Comment: You are mixing scanf syntax and printf syntax. They are not same. And reason screen disappears because code ends there. Try running your application from command line

Comment: You should work on the formatting of your code. Get inspired by the samples in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: Voting to close as "simple typographical error"; remove the `&` from `printf`.

Comment: @BarbaraSweeney Do *not* write "Thank you!......." comments. They're bad on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove & before num1 and num2 (&num will give you memory location of that variable)

```
if(num1 > num2)
        {printf ("%d is the larger number.\n", num1);
        }
        else if (num1 < num2)
        {printf ("%d is the larger number.\n", num2);
        }
```

Comment: "(&num will give you memory location of that variable)" - and you'd need to adjust the format specifier to something like `%p` and ideally cast to `void*` at the calling site, else the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In your `printf()` statements, you're giving the address of the variable to be printed instead of the value of the variable. When the prefix `&` is used for a variable, it gives the address of the variable in memory rather than it's value. To get the value of the variable, just use the variable name without the `&` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

**&** sign before num1 and num2 is giving you the memory location of the variable num1 and num2. If you want to see the value of num1 and num2, use the following code segment.

```
int main(void){
int num1;
int num2;
printf("Enter a whole number: ");
scanf ("%d", &num1);
printf("\nEnter a different whole number for evaluation: ");
scanf ("%d", &num2);
if(num1 > num2)
    {printf ("\n%d is the larger number.", num1);
    }
else
    {printf ("\n%d is the larger number.", num2);
    }
return 0;}
```